# String literal as argument for func within println?

Tags: ios, function, swift

Is there anyway to use a string literal as an argument to a function within a println statement.

```
func greetings(name: String) -> String {
    return "Greetings \(name)!"
}
```

What I was trying to do: (I tried escaping the quotes around Earthling.)

```
println("OUTPUT: \(greetings("Earthling"))")
```

You can alternatively do this:

```
let name = "Earthling"
println("OUTPUT: \(greetings(name))")
```

And this works too:

```
println(greetings("Earthling"))
```

I tried escaping the quotes in the first example but with no luck, its not super important as its only a test, I was just curious if there was a way to do this, using a function call with a string literal as an argument within a print or println statement that contains other text.

Comment: You commented on your own question. Very confusing. :S

Comment: Ah. I thought he had meant to comment on your answer and missed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apple docs:

> The expressions you write inside parentheses within an interpolated
>   string cannot contain an unescaped double quote (") or backslash (\),
>   and cannot contain a carriage return or line feed.

Comment: Ah cool, thank you, that sums things up ... Much appreciated.

Comment: Note also that since you can't put use a backslash, you also can't put an escaped double quote in...  The only way to do it is to put the string literal in a variable and use that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is of course not with `println` but with the embedding of expressions with quotes in string literals.
Thus

```
let b = false
let s1 = b ? "is" : "isn't"
let s2 = "it \(b ? "is" : "isn't")" // won't compile
```

However NSLog as a one-liner'' works quite well here

```
NSLog("it %@", b ? "is" : "isn't")
```

Note `%@`, not `%s`. Try the latter in a playground to see why.